# Verify user password using Authorization Services

Tags: c#, macos, cocoa, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I'm writing OS X application and I want to check if current user have **empty** password. I tried to use `Authorization Services` for it

```
var env = new AuthorizationEnvironment();
env.Password = "";
env.Username = <MyUserName>;

using (var auth = Authorization.Create(
    null,
    env,
    AuthorizationFlags.Defaults))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Auth obtained: " + (auth != null));
}
```

but it always printing *"Auth obtained: True"*.

I tried to pass `AuthorizationParameters` but I can't find what `PathToSystemPrivilegeTool` I should use since then its printing *"Auth obtained: False"* with any value.

Could, please, someone point me a direction which I should look for?